Sequence of tenses
Is it correct to say "I was where he had told me that I was right"?
Meaning that "had told" and "was right" happened at the same moment

What are you trying to say with this? If you want to express that two things happened at the same time, you use "when", not "where"

How is this different from https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/358218/about-sequence-of-tenses ?

The sentence is syntactically correct if semantically weird but it doesn’t mean what you think it means
Let’s break it down:
“I was” - so this happened in the past, because if it was happening now it would be “I am” and if it was going to happen “I will be”.
“where” - ok, it’s a place (not necessarily a physical place, could be a metaphorical place) where you were.
“he had told me” - at this place but before this time you had been told something.
“that I was right” - We’ve reached the end and we know that he told you you were right. We don’t know what you were right about or when or whether you continue you to be right, but at some time at or before the time you were told, you were right about it.
So there are three events:

In the past, you were at a place. This might be a physical place or it might be an allegorical place like an emotional state.
Further back in the past, someone had told you something at that place.
Perhaps at the same time but maybe also further back in the past, you had been right about something. Where you were right is not disclosed.

The entire purpose of “where he had told me that I was right” is to identify the place where you were. The person that you are talking to will use this part of the sentence primarily to locate you.
This is how “I was where the Declaration of Independence was signed” is equivalent to “I was at Independence Hall, Philadelphia” and “I was where English kings are crowned” equals “I was at Westminster Abbey, London”.
